# freescale imx pin control driver, how groups are calculated?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am trying to understand im.X pin controller driver from Linux Kernel.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pinctrl/pinctrl-imx.c?v=3.10#L513

I dump the values of info->ngroups = 38  and info->nfunctions = 2 but failed to understand how value of info->ngroups been calculated to 38 , this is the respected DTS files ?

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q.dtsi?v=4.1#L104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the DTS file you refer is a `.dtsi`. It is not a real board DTS and it is (must be) included by another DTS file, for instance [imx6q-sbc6x.dts](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q-sbc6x.dts?v=4.1). In this DTS file, other functions with further pins are defined and that's why you can have, for instance, `nfunctions = 2` and `ngroups = 38`.

If you find the correct DTS file for your board, these numbers should "align" with what you see in your dump.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what you said make sense to me. imx6q-nitrogen6x.dts is actual board file which includes imx6q.dtsi and imx6qdl-nitrogen6x.dtsi but still can't under stand how it counts to 38 here and just 2 functions ?

Comment: Well the 2 functions are the 2 children of the `iomuxc@020e0000` node, namely `ipu2` from [imx6q.dtsi](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q.dtsi?v=4.1) and `imx6q-nitrogen6x` from [imx6qdl-nitrogen6x.dtsi](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-nitrogen6x.dtsi?v=4.1). The 38 groups are then all the "group "children of these 2 nodes, like for instance `ipu2grp-1` or `enetgrp` respectively.